# ps user-defined output in RHEL 6.2

Tags: bash, rhel, ps

I am relatively new to using `ps`. I cannot get `ps` to provide user-definend output in RHEL 6.2 using `-o` or `o` options. Simplest example, `ps -o pid` works in a [BASH shell fiddle](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php)

```
sh-4.2$ ps -o pid                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 PID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 19                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 29
```

But in the RHEL 6.2 VM I only get errors:

```
[root@foobar ram]# ps -o pid
ERROR: Conflicting format options.
********* simple selection *********  ********* selection by list *********
-A all processes                      -C by command name
<...more...>
```

I've tried some other variations found online with no luck. Is there an issue with the particular syntax with RHEL 6.2? Would setting/changing the `PS_PERSONALITY` enviromental variable help?

Answer (score 1):

You evidently have a wrapper for `ps` — probably an alias, perhaps a function or script. Check with `type ps`.

Your wrapper defines some format option to make it the default for your `ps` command. `ps -o pid` requests both that default and `-o pid`, hence the complaint from `/bin/ps`. If you want to bypass this default, you have a few choices:

- Invoke `/bin/ps` instead of plain `ps`.
- If the wrapper is an alias, invoke `\ps`.
- If the wrapper is an alias or function, invoke `command ps`.
- Change the wrapper to be smarter — but that means parsing the `ps` command line, which is not for the faint of heart.
- Don't use that wrapper at all.

Comment: We have a winner! Many thanks. It had an alias. The \ps invocation worked.